# I updated Python to a newer version, now running python in my virtualenv prints out errors

Tags: python, virtualenv

I get this error when I try to run python

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\djangoproject>python
    Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

    Current thread 0x000021f0 (most recent call first):
```

I use window 7, it runs without errors in CMD but when I activate the virtualenv it still prints out that error. I had Python 3.6.2 installed previously, I uninstalled it and installed 3.6.7 that's when my problem began.

Note: I created the Virtualenv with 3.6.2

Any ideas on how I can fix this please??

Comment: So how did you update python to a newer version?

Comment: What versions of Python did you upgrade from and to? Did you try recreating the new virtualenv under the new Python? Or if you are on Python 3.3+, consider using the included `venv`.

Comment: The previous python version is 3.6.2 and the newly installed version is 3.6.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it already. I followed @FlipperPA 's advice and recreated the new virtualenv under the new python. Here's how I went about it:

```
C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\djangoproject> oldvenv\Scripts\activate
(oldvenv) C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\djangoproject> pip3 freeze —local > requirements.txt
```

The `pip3 freeze —local > requirements.txt` generates a file with the versions of all the packages you have installed. It can be used later to re-install all those packages.

Then I deactivated the virtualenv `oldvenv\Scripts\deactivate` and deleted it i.e deleting the virtualenv folder. I then created a new virtual environment using `python3 -m venv myvenv`.
And finally I ran 
`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, and everything worked correctly again!

I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

We need more Info to help you out , such as what kind of windows you have ? and how did you try to update Python ? and more info about what you've done specifically , whatever it happens usually on win 10 , So try this following steps I've fixed it through :

1.Open your '**Environment Variables**' (Under '**System Properties**'). 
 
2.In the window that opens, select the 'Path' row, then click the '**Edit...**' button.
3.There is should be two environment variables C:\Python37-32\Scripts\ and C:\Python37-32\ Then click '**OK**' (Make sure to check that these path values correspond to the location and version of your Python install.)
4.Next, in the top portion of the '**Environment Variables**' window, look for the PYTHONHOME variable and make sure that it is also set to C:\Python37-32 
If that didn't work as well , and still have the same issue , I'll give you another way to try : 
Close all CMD or console emulator.

Go to the system environment settings and clear all old Python path or environment settings. Make sure you check the PATH in both User and System settings as well

Try again python -V and see can you run it or not

If you have removed all Python environment settings, I recommend you to reinstall Python and turn on the Add Python to PATH setting during installation.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response @Mohammed Rizqallah, I use window 7, it runs without errors in CMD but when I activate the virtualenv it still prints out that error.               I had Python 3.6.2 installed previously, I uninstalled it and installed 3.6.7 that's when my problem began. Thanks for your assistance.